# Spark get the default pool scheduling mode programmatically

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to get the default pool scheduler mode programmatically (with spark context). However, the `sc.get("spark.scheduler.mode")` does not seem to work when we have multiple pool configured. [image: My pool configuration].

How do I get the `default` pool scheduling mode programatically?
Note: I am using 3.3.1 version of spark.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Spark scheduling documentaion](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) `sc.get("spark.scheduler.mode")` will return whether `FIFO` or `FAIR`. If you need to get scheduler pool name, need to use `sc.getLocalProperty(SparkContext.SPARK_SCHEDULER_POOL)`